# Частичная обфускация

Tags: android

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемой частичной обфускации? Класс обфуцируется частично. Некоторые методы меняют название, а некоторые нет

вот мой proGuard файл

```
    #nav models
-keep class * extends android.os.Parcelable
-keep class * extends java.io.Serializable

#koin
-keepclassmembers public class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel { public <init>(...); }

#netwok
-keep class com.umbrella.ds_remote_impl.** {*;}

#moshi & DriverProfileEditableDataSectionType
-keepclassmembernames class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
}
```

а вот пример методов customView первый из которых обфуцируется, а другие нет

```
 /* renamed from: a */
    public final void mo27123a(C3428a<C4785t> callback) {
        C3753r.m3233g(callback, "callback");
        ShapeableImageView shapeableImageView = this.f18625q.f19116b;
        C3753r.m3232f(shapeableImageView, "binding.iconPlaceholder");
        C10238r.m40740h(shapeableImageView, 0, new UploadPhotoWithReplaceIcon$onReplaceIconClick$1(callback), 1);
    }

    public final void setBitmapBackground(Bitmap image) {
        C3753r.m3233g(image, "image");
        this.f18625q.f19117c.setBitmapBackground(image);
    }

    public final void setImageBackground(String imageUrl) {
        C3753r.m3233g(imageUrl, "imageUrl");
        this.f18625q.f19117c.setImageBackground(imageUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Если они часть какого-то публичного API, то могут и не меняться.

Comment: Это код из моих custom view. Написан мною. В данном классе нет никаких использований библиотек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть стандартные правила обфускации для Андроида и у вас они наверняка подключены:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

[`proguard-android-optimize.txt`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt) содержит правило:

```
# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
```

Которое запрещает переименовывать геттеры и сеттеры в классах, наследниках `View`

Comment: гетеры и сеттры это не методы. Если выключить R8 в properties android.enableR8=false, то минификация происходит более качественно. Проблема решилась.

Comment: В каком смысле не методы? `setBitmapBackground` - это именно сеттер и он подпадает под вышеозначенное правило. Просто отключив R8 вы задействуете прогуард из Android SDK, который там давным давно не обновляется и не знает про особенности современной сборки Андроид-приложений, это может привести к нежданчикам на ровном месте. Если хотите прогуард - сходите на его сайт и почитайте как задействовать свежую версию в Андроид-проекте. Собственно в репозитории и можно почитать: https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard

Comment: Вы правы. Вместе с выключением R8 я убрал getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')

Comment: дефолтные правила использовать обязательно?

Comment: Необязательно, но там минимальный набор, необходимый для Андроида. Посмотрите содержимое этого файла - не думаю что найдёте там лишнее. Конечно можно его не использовать и настроить всё самолично как душе угодно.